# Modifying the checkout process in Prestashop 1.5

Tags: php, paypal, e-commerce, prestashop

A client of us has developed a payment gateway, similar to PayPal. He wants a module for Prestashop, for making clients to be able to pay through it.

He wants to modify the original checkout process. For example, if the user introduces a concrete postal code, the only available way to pay must be his payment gateway. Is it possible? I don't know exactly if this is allowed by the Prestashop API or even if this can be done.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible.
You just have to create a specific payment module with the good Hook.

Comment: That's the plan. But i was not sure about modifying that part of the checkout flow process. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The best solution maybe is to create your own payment module, 
You could easily extend the PaymentModule class and create your own with your own logic.

**Make a custom module**
[see Creating a payment module official documentation](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Creating+a+payment+module)

When you extend the PaymentModule you inherit all from the parent class, so you could add your new methods or override the inhereted ones.
Fortunally that abstract class doesn't have abstract methods, that means that just extending it you will have all the basic payment behaviour pre built in.

[Source of the PaymentModule](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/cc29166f3509895c8fd6de39c5aae2c98e942637/classes/PaymentModule.php)

**Hooks**
In the offical documentation about creating a payment module there is a mention for making some hooks:

- payment: to display the payment method.
- paymentReturn: to display the payment confirmation.

making that hooks is simple, just define inside your custom payment class methods named hookPayment and hookPaymentReturn.

[Hooks in Prestashop](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Hooks+in+PrestaShop+1.5)

**Others useful links**
You could also have a look of some famous payment module like Paypal, to understand better how it works and having some thinking about your module.

[Prestashop Paypal Module source](https://github.com/PrestaShop/paypal/blob/2fad5f9ae414eea4919c29662c6a5b602b1dabf6/paypal.php)

Comment: I got that already thanks for the help. but now, all my jquery features suddenly gone, jquery main file is linked. any help would be wonderful.

Comment: sorry, I don't understand because your jquery features are gone, which kind of features did you have? Can't you hack the template and reinsert that?

Comment: i had done many things.. i think its some conflict error... some js operations are working but some others not responding. firebug shows TypeError: $(...).carousel is not a function

Comment: maybe is Jcarousel that use Jquery, so sometimes if you have other plugins, there could be some conflicts in between. Try to remove from the page plugins one by one to see who cause the problem

Comment: thanks for the help. anyway js is still a problem... is prestashop a MVC? i couldn't get the code flow at all... this thing is very hard to learn..

Comment: Yes, follows the MVC design, [read the documentation](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Fundamentals+of+PrestaShop+Development)